# A heap manager for C/Pascal that automatically fills freed memory with zero bytes

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, shared-memory, free

What do you think about an option to fill freed (not actually used) pages with zero bytes? This may improve performance under Windows, and also under VMWare and other virtual machine environments? For example, VMWare and HyperV calculate hash of memory pages, and, if the contents is the same, mark this page as "shared" inside a virtual machine and between virtual machines on the same host, until the page is modified. It effectively decreases memory consumption. Windows does the same - it handles zero pages differently, treating them as free.

We could have the heap manager that would automatically fill memory with zeros when we call FreeMem/ReallocMem. As an alternative option, we could have a function that zeroizes empty memory by demand, i.e. only when this function is explicitly called. Of course, this function has to be thread-safe.
The drawback of filling memory with zeros is touching the memory, which might have already been turned into virtual, thus issuing page faults. Besides that, any memory store operations are slow, so our program will be slower, albeit to an unknown extent (maybe negligible).

If we manage to fill 4-K pages completely with zeros, the hypervisor or Windows will explicitly mark it as a zero page. But even partial zeroizing may be beneficial, since the hypervisor may compress pages using LZ or similar algorithms to save physical memory.

I just want to know your opinion whether the benefits of filling emptied heap memory with zero bytes by the heap manager itself will outweigh the disadvantages of such a technique.

Is zeroizing worth its price when we buy reduced physical memory consumption?

Comment: I wonder if any "secure" languages or OSes do something like this to minimize the risk of attacks on the system being able to find critical (but no longer in use) data.

Comment: @manassehkatz - thank you for the nice observation. Delays caused by zeroizing memory for secure languages is justified. My question was pointed to other direction: efficiency of memory use caused by deduplication of zero pages. Is zeroizing worth its price when we buy reduced physical memory consumption?

Answer (score 7):

When you have a page whose contents you no longer care about but you still want to keep it allocated, you can call `VirtualAlloc` (and variants) and pass the `MEM_RESET` flag.

From [`VirtualAlloc` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **`MEM_RESET`**
>
> Indicates that data in the memory range specified by lpAddress and
>   dwSize is no longer of interest. The pages should not be read from or
>   written to the paging file. However, the memory block will be used
>   again later, so it should not be decommitted. This value cannot be
>   used with any other value.
>
> Using this value does not guarantee that
>   the range operated on with MEM_RESET will contain zeros. If you want
>   the range to contain zeros, decommit the memory and then recommit it.

This gives the best of both worlds - you don't have the cost of zeroing the memory, and the system does not have the cost of paging it back in.  You get to take advantage of the well-tuned memory manager which already has a zero-pool.

Similar functionality also exists on Linux under the `MADV_FREE` (or `MADV_DONTNEED` for Posix) flag to `madvise`.  [Glibc uses this function in the implementation of its heap.](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/cf2046ec7dd4b233180377cc5b8debcf551d1fc9/malloc/arena.c#L581):

```
/* 
 * Stack:
 * int shrink_heap (heap_info *h, long diff)
 * int heap_trim (heap_info *heap, size_t pad) at arena.c:660
 * void _int_free (mstate av, mchunkptr p, int have_lock) at malloc.c:4097
 * void __libc_free (void *mem) at malloc.c:2948
 * void free(void *mem)
 */

static int
shrink_heap (heap_info *h, long diff)
{
  long new_size;

  new_size = (long) h->size - diff;
  /* ... snip ...  */

  __madvise ((char *) h + new_size, diff, MADV_DONTNEED);

  /* ... snip ...  */
  h->size = new_size;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your heap is in user space this will never work. The kernel can only trust itself, not user space. If the kernel zeros a page, it can treat it as zero. If user space says it zeroed a page, the kernel would still have to check that. It might just as well zero it. One thing user space can do is to discard pages. Which marks them as "don't care". Then a kernel can treat them as zero. But manually zeroing pages in user space is futile.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think that your explanation only applies to Windows when it runs on physical hardware. But if Windows is running under VMWare ESXi or HyperV, your explanation does not apply, isn't it? See: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/memory_counters.html
https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2015/01/assess-the-performance-impact-of-the-security-change-in-transparent-page-sharing-behaviour.html
http://www.hakabo.com/web/2016/05/transparent-page-sharing-tps/
http://vmnomad.blogspot.md/2011/06/vsphere-transparent-page-sharing.html

Comment: Maybe we should check a CPUID bit: if we run under HyperVisor - clear the memory, otherwise don't clear.

Comment: This is not even true when running on bare metal.  Windows [does check that a page is all zeros when paging out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161109-00/?p=94675).

Comment: @Mitch: I think we pretty much agree on the concept. I think your answer is  much better in giving actual documentation and advice on what to do!